# How to get React Error Boundary to reset state with Try Again button?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query, react-error-boundary

My Pokemon application is using the following libraries: React Hook Form, React Query, and React Error Boundary.

When a request hasn't been made, it will should render `No Pokemon Yet, Please Submit a Pokemon.` When an error occurs, a `Try Again` button will render in place of `No Pokemon Yet, Please Submit a Pokemon`. When the `Try Again` button is clicked, `No Pokemon Yet, Please Submit a Pokemon` will again be shown and the search input is reset with the user again able to make a query.

However, my implementation is not working. Initially, `No Pokemon Yet, Please Submit a Pokemon` is not being rendered prior to the user submitting a query. Also, when I type a query that doesn't have any matches, the error boundary is not triggering to tell the user what has happened and allow them to resubmit a query after clicking the `Try Again` button. The DevTools Network tab gives me a 404.

React Error Boundary will only trigger if the `img` from `PokemonInfo` is uncommented. It renders `Cannot read property 'front_default' of undefined`.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems in your example:

1. you are `catch`ing the error in the queryFn. react-query expects a failed promise to be returned in order to handle errors. If you catch it (just to log it as you're doing it), it will be a resolved Promise, hence no error. For logging errors, use the `onError` callback.
2. in order to use error boundaries to handle errors, you need to set the property `useErrorBoundary: true`. This is best described on the suspense page in the docs, but you don't need to use it together with suspense: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/suspense

Comment: Thank you for your solution attempt. I've added `useErrorBoundary: true` and it is now rendering `Request failed with status code 404` when a submitted query does not have any matches in db. However, could you provide an implementation of `onError` as the docs are not clear to me and have not found helpful examples online.

Comment: `useQuery(key, queryFn, { onError: (error) => console.log(error) })`

Comment: Thanks, I'm now going to work on getting the application to recover from the error boundary when `Try Again` is clicked.